# How to use localstorage in Titanium/Alloy?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I am very new to Appcelerator/Titanium. Can anyone tell me how to use **localstorage** function in **Alloy** (Titanium). (Not getting any good solution on Web).

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Titanium Alloy has a customized implemntación Backbone. This means that titanium uses Backbone for many things, but at the same time some important features have been left out.

One of the most used parts of Backbone by Titanium are models, while that not identical to those ofrese the js framework, they have lots of things in common.

To work with data models must define an adapter (this can be localStorage, sql, properties or custom sync adapters)

If you want to work with localStorage, your model should look something like this:

```
exports.definition = {

config: {
    "defaults": {
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "phone": "",
        "email": ""
    },
    "adapter": {
        "type": 'localStorage',
        "collection_name": 'user'
    }
},

extendModel: function(Model) {
    _.extend(Model.prototype, {
    }); // end extend

    return Model;
},

extendCollection: function(Collection) {
    _.extend(Collection.prototype, {
    }); // end extend

    return Collection;
}
```

};

to manipulate the data then you should use:

Create data

```
model = Alloy.createModel('user', {first_name: 'Pedro', last_name: Picapiedra});
// or model.save();
Alloy.Collections.user.add(model);
```

Read data

```
callection = Alloy.Collections.user.fetch()
model = Alloy.Collections.user.get(modelId)
```

Update data

```
user.set({
    first_name : 'Pablo',
    last_name : 'Marmol',
});

user.save();
```

Delete data

```
model.destroy();
collection.remove(model);
```

For more information:

[Titanium Sync & apadters](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Sync_Adapters_and_Migrations)

[Backbone Sync, collections, models & etc](http://docs.appcelerator.com/backbone/0.9.2/)

Comment: Is this syntax reserved for the localstorage adapter? I assumed it would also work with the sql adapter, but I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 0):

See https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Working+with+Local+Data+Sources for general guide.

Accessing files is done through the Ti.Filesystem. See documentation at http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem . You should also see the kitchen sink example, as it shows hot to read/write file https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/ui/common/platform/filesystem.js.

If you simply want to store some data locally, many people use sqlite database. See http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Database .

The simplest way is to use properties. It is limited, but for many people that is enough. http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties

Comment: nothing that you have referenced here explains how to use localStorage  with Alloy?

Comment: Fair enough. From the question I did not get that he wanted to access HTML5 functionality. I assumed he missed a space and wanted access to "local storage", a general term meaning "a catch-all term referring to any of several mechanisms for storing data on a client machine".